# Get jquery's .append() to return the wrapped set containing the appended object not the container

Tags: jquery, append

I want to append an html element to a div and have jquery return me the wrapped set that contains the element I just appended and not the wrapped set containing the div

So my html:-

```
...

<div id="somediv">Some other elements...</div>

...
```

javascript:-

```
var jqueryObj = $('#somediv').append('<p>Hello, World!</p>');

alert(jqueryObj.html());
```

I'd like this to alert me with `'Hello, world'` not `'Some other elements...<p>Hello, World!</p>'`

Comment: you would have to save the html content before you append the new content, and after appending remove the content that you saved from the new. But why don't you simply save the value of what you are appending to a variable and use .text() method ?

Comment: Sorry, this was mearly a test case that I setup - I don't actually want the text of the containing paragraph, I want to apply a jquery ui dialog to the jquery object

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead of [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
var jqueryObj = $('<p>Hello, World!</p>').appendTo('#somediv');
alert(jqueryObj.html()); // '<p>Hello, World!</p>'
```

Comment: Woah! my first ever post to SO, I had no idea how quick the responses would be so quick!! Amazing :)

Answer (score 3):

Switch them around, and use the [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) function. Like so:

```
var jqueryObj = $('<p>Hello, World!</p>').appendTo('#somediv');
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wse7/)

Comment: Perfect, thankyou! I would give you a +1 but I don't have 15 reputations yet!

Answer (score 0):

```
var jqueryObj = $('#somediv').append('<p>Hello, World!</p>');

alert(jqueryObj.find("p").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jqueryObj= $('<p>Hello, world!</p>');
$('#somediv').append(jqueryObj);

alert(jqueryObj.html());
```

What you want is the variable to actually hold the newly created object, not the div into which you added it.